# Proof that a cokernel of an injective morphisme between injective objects is injective

Tags: abelian-categories

I am trying to prove the following fact : Let $\Phi : A \to B$ an injective morphisme between two injective objects in an abelian category. Show that $Coker( \Phi)$ is also an injective object.

I have already tried many ways but I still did not succeed to get a proper proof. Here's how I proceed :
Let $C$ and $D$ two objects of $\mathscr{C}$ such as there's an injection $j \ : C\ \to D$ and a morphism from $C \to Coker \Phi$. As $Coker \Phi $ is the data of an object $Coker \Phi$ of $\mathscr{C}$ and a morphism $\chi_{Coker\phi} : B \to Coker \Phi$ and as $B$ is injective, I am trying to build an injective arrow $j$ from $Coker \Phi \to B$ such as $\chi_{Coker \phi}\circ j =Id_{Coker \Phi}$. Indeed, if such an arrow is built we can conclude as B is an injective object.

My problem is how to build properly such an arrow, using the fact that $\Phi $ is injective and also $A$ is injective. I have already tried to show that $Ker(\chi _{Coker \Phi})$ is $A$ but without success. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every short exact sequence
$$0\to A\to B\to C\to0$$
with $A$ an injective object, splits. Therefore $B\cong A\oplus C$.
If $B$ is also an injective object, then $C$ is a direct summand
of an injective object, and so is a injective object itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
As I am a beginner, in abelian catgories, I would like to show first that this is an exact sequence thanks to the general definitions of surjectivity and injectivity. I succeed to show that $B\to Coker \ \Phi $ is surjective, and to build a map $i : A \to Ker \ \chi_{Coker \Phi}$ vérifying $$ \Phi = \chi_{Ker \ \chi_{Coker \Phi}} \circ i $$ . I showed that this one was injective , ie $Hom(Ker \  i, A)=0$ but I can't show properly  that it's surjective, ie $Hom(Ker \ \chi_{Coker \Phi}, Coker \  i ) =0$. I have tried many ways, but still did not find the trick.